# Are dropbear and OpenSSH host keys compatible?

Tags: ssh, openssh, dropbear

The title basically says it all. But mind: **host key**, not the login key.

And if they're not compatible out of the box, is there a way to convert between them - and what would be the steps in that case?

Rationale: it would be nice to be able to bring up a dropbear instance in the scope of the initrd, if boot fails, but do so by incorporating the host keys (via initramfs-tools hooks) from OpenSSH that is normally installed on the host.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After the misunderstanding that I am referring to **host** keys instead of **login** keys, I decided to dig into this a little myself. The main point was to establish whether the formats are **compatible**, not whether they're different (I knew they are).

Trying to install dropbear over a system that already had OpenSSH of course failed miserably, but this wasn't the point of the exercise. During the installation (and before the failure) the output said:

```
Converting existing OpenSSH RSA host key to Dropbear format.
```

So a quick `apt-get source dropbear` and `grep`-ing inside the `debian` subfolder yielded:

```
dropbear.postinst:    echo "Converting existing OpenSSH RSA host key to Dropbear format."
```

Promising. The relevant lines in the `dropbear.postinst` script read:

```
echo "Converting existing OpenSSH RSA host key to Dropbear format."
/usr/lib/dropbear/dropbearconvert openssh dropbear \
  /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key
```

Apparently `dropbear` comes with a tool named `dropbearconvert`, which has a `.c` source file in the source and comes with a `man` page: `dropbearconvert(1)`. Because I was unable to come up with an online version of the man page, here the gist:

```
SYNOPSIS
       dropbearconvert input_type output_type input_file output_file

[...]

OPTIONS
       input type
              Either dropbear or openssh

       output type
              Either dropbear or openssh

       input file
              An existing Dropbear or OpenSSH private key file

       output file
              The path to write the converted private key file
```

Comment: Turns out it's silly and old-style to prepare by reading the documentation. Simply do it - fail - but see the indication that the conversion is possible in the output of the failed installation. Oh well ... I guess my old-fart-RTFM-first attitude doesn't work anymore :)

Comment: Strange, my system has a man page for `dropbearconvert`, but doesn't seem to have the program in the path. I did `dpkg -L dropbear` and found it is installed under `/usr/lib/dropbear/dropbearconvert`.

Comment: I found [this man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dropbearconvert.1.html) from ubuntu

Comment: Did you actually have this work though? I get Error: Unrecognised key type for the rsa or any other private keys running as sudo

Comment: converting the private keys with ssh-keygen -m PEM -f /tmp/openssh.key first results in Error: File does not begin with OpenSSH key header

Comment: Dropbear can be compiled with all related commands in one binary. The other commands are accessed by creating a symlinks in the same way as busybox. To obtain the public key, use `dropbearkey -y -f /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key | grep -v 'Fingerprint: sha1!!\|Public key'`

Comment: Note that `dropbearconvert` only implemented the new OpenSSH format (not the old legacy PEM Format) private key  handling since "Dropbear 2022.82" (1 Apr 2022). Keys can now be read in OpenSSH format or the old PEM format. ED25519 support was broken before and has now been fixed also. DSS keys are still PEM format. See: https://github.com/mkj/dropbear/releases